# Several UIButton title changing

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I am new in iphone programming. I would like to know how can i change several UIButtons' title simultaneously. For example, there are ten UIButtons and i want when i click first one the remaining ones' titles change. Thanks for your help.

Comment: when action method of button clicked runs, inside it you have to set the title of each button

Comment: set unique tags all buttons in view and use viewWithTag option to set tile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it, if you want to change all other buttons in the view is to iterate the subviews of the `UIView` that contains the `UIButtons`.

```
- (void)buttonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    for (id subview in self.view.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] && subview != sender) {
            UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
            [button setTitle:@"new title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the buttons in an array (if they are in IB usd an IBOutletCollection). Then when they need to change use a for statement to iterate through the array.